# how to add date-column to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, date, merge, addition

I have a data frame with many different columns (each column has 10 rows/entries) and I want to add a date-column as the first column to this data frame. The date column should end today and starts today-9.
The following data frame is just a counterexample:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(DE = rnorm(10, 2, 1), Wind = rnorm(10, 5, 2), Solar = rnorm(10, 2, 2))
```

So in this case the date-column should be `c("2020-10-10", ..., "2020-10-19")`.

How can I add such an cate-column which depends on the current date, like today is the 19th Oct., so the date should start `today()-9`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `seq.Date` function to generate such a list. Here we use the number of rows in the `df` but you could hard-code 10 if you prefer

```
date_vals <- rev(seq(Sys.Date(), by="-1 days", length.out=nrow(df)))
```

We start at 10, walk back a certain number of steps, and then reverse the list to get the oldest date first.

You could also specify both dates as well

```
date_vals <- seq(Sys.Date()-9, Sys.Date(), by="1 day")
```

Then, which ever way you create the values, you can add them as the first column of your data.frame with this

```
df <- data.frame(dates=date_vals, df)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I add this column on the first place? Now it is the last column of ```df```.